# When is a solution concept sensible?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

For many parabolic PDE (systems), one has to weaken the solution concept in order to obtain global solutions. Apart from *classical solutions*, the most known concept is surely that of *weak solutions*, where one requires that the equation(s) at hand is (are) fulfilled in a distributional sense.

Another (and at least intuitively weaker) solution concept is the following: $u$ is called a *renormalized solution* if $\phi(u)$ is a weak solution of the corresponding equation, where $\phi$ is for instance some function with positive derivative. Alternatively, one requires this for a class of functions, e.g. for all $\phi$ with compact support.

Yet other concepts incorporate entropy or energy identities in the definition or replace equalities by inequalities etc.

All these concepts seem to be too strong for a problem (a parabolic system) I am considering right now and hence my intent is to invent a novel solution concept. However, there is a important question here: **What makes a solution concept sensible?**

A minimal requirement should be that smooth solutions fulfilling the new concept should also be classical solutions but, unfortunately, that does not seem to be enough. For instance,

> $u : \overline \Omega \times [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ is a solution of $u_t = \Delta u$ (along with some initial and boundary conditions) if the equation is fulfilled for each $(x, t) \in \Omega \times (0, \infty)$, where $u$ is smooth.

(here and in the example below, the heat equation is just taken for illustrative purposes) is quite obviously a nonsensical (sketch of a) solution concept -- although smooth solutions fulfilling this concept are classical solutions: Each solution which is nowhere smooth is a solution. Of course, this concept is designed mainly as a counter example to the claim that *a solution concept is sensible iff smooth such solutions are classical solutions*.

**Are the criteria which one can use to test whether a solution concept is sensible?** Uniqueness is an obvious candidate but that can generally not be expected (not even for weak or renormalized solutions).

As a more concrete example, is the following concept interesting? If yes, what arguments can one give to support that claim?

> $u : \overline \Omega \times [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ is a solution of $u_t = \Delta u$ (along with some initial and boundary conditions) if there is $x_0 \in \Omega$ such that the weak formulation is fulfilled for all test functions belonging to $C_{\mathrm{loc}}^\infty(\Omega \setminus \{x_0\} \times [0, \infty))$.